# Where can one find the MontaVista CGE 6.0 kernel sources

Tags: linux-kernel

I think the mvista carrier grade linux's 2.6.32 kernel *should* be available somewhere on the internet because of the kernel GPL license (I assume it is **not** vanilla kernel), but I seem not to be able to locate it from mvista website or via google.

Where can I find it?

[source.mvista.com](http://source.mvista.com) has been giving `connection refused` for last few months.

Comment: Since when is "Where" not a real question?

Comment: Please note that the GPL does not dictate the sources need to be made public. They only need to be made available to whomever receives a binary of them or a written offer to supply them. Therefore, they might not be available.

Comment: Yes, it is so. Check the GPL v2, article 3, sub articles a and b (c not relevant since this is a commercial distribution): http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html

Comment: subarticle b says __any third party__ - I read that as public, but I see that actually since MontaVista only distributes the _source code_ they do not have to care about GPL, only their customers do...

Comment: sub article b says they need to provide a written offer to the recipient to provide the source code on request to any third party, they don't need to make the source code public. At any rate, since they provide the source to their customers they are covered by sub article a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can find a copy of MV Linux source kernels on MV meld.org site. While they are not officially called CGL kernels I suspect they are very close or even the same.

Go to http://meld.org , create a user for yourself (it's free) and check out the Library => SDK page

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks. "Your account is pending for admin approval." Hope this works. :)

Comment: AFAIK it is no more then anti spam moderation. They approved me with no problem even though I never was a MV customer

Comment: There it was. Well hidden, but still there. The kernel tarball is `toolchain/tools/i686-gnu/i686-montavista-linux-gnu/sources/linux.tar.bz2` inside the downloadable tarball

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for
http://source.mvista.com/gittrees/linux-davinci-2.6.git/
this source tree does not seam to work?

here is a download link for the source code 
http://products.sel.sony.com/linux/source/linux-2.4.18_mvl21-x.tar.gz

Comment: Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED): The server refused the connection.

Comment: thats all the information i have on this but it might be behind firewalls or it might have been moved